# How to use GROUP with DATEPART?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following script to count the number of ShopId for one year.

I need also to breakdown the result by month for a year.

So end result should be

```
MONTH 1
    SHOPID 5     100
    SHOPID 4     90
MONTH 2
    SHOPID 1     150
    SHOPID 4     80
```

---

```
   SELECT ShopId, Count(ShopId) as Interest
    FROM dbo.Analytics
    WHERE DateCreated >= '2014' AND DateCreated < '2015'
    GROUP BY ShopId ORDER BY Interest DESC
```

---

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE Analytics
(
DateCreated dateTime2(2),
ShopId  int
);
```

What Should I change in my script? Shall I use DATEPART near GROUP BY

Comment: Any suggestion for a better title are welcome :-)

Comment: DateCreated is DateTime field?

Comment: Please also post your table structure

Comment: @Raj Table structure added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)**.

Try like this

```
    SELECT DatePart(mm,datecreated) 'Month',ShopId, Count(ShopId) as Interest
    FROM dbo.Analytics
    WHERE year(DateCreated) = '2015' 
    GROUP BY Datepart(mm,datecreated),ShopId 
    ORDER BY Interest DESC
```

DatePart will return Month Number only. If you need Result would have Month Name then you should use **DateName**

Try this

```
    SELECT Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , DatePart(mm,datecreated) , -1 ) ) 'Month',ShopId, Count(ShopId) as Interest
    FROM dbo.Analytics
    WHERE year(DateCreated) = '2015' 
    GROUP BY DateName( month , DateAdd( month , DatePart(mm,datecreated) , -1 ) ),ShopId 
    ORDER BY Interest DESC
```

Comment: How would you order by month?

Comment: @GibboK Just use `Order By DatePart(mm,datecreated)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    SELECT datepart(mm,datecreated) 'Month',ShopId, Count(ShopId) as Interest
    FROM dbo.Analytics
    WHERE year(DateCreated) = '2014' 
    GROUP BY datepart(mm,datecreated),ShopId ORDER BY Interest DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT      DATEPART(MONTH, DateCreated) AS MONTH, ShopId, COUNT(ShopId) AS Interest
FROM        dbo.Analytics
WHERE       YEAR(DateCreated) = '2014'
GROUP BY    DATEPART(MONTH, DateCreated), ShopId
ORDER BY    DATEPART(MONTH, DateCreated) ASC, Interest DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you gonna need to group the year too incase there is wider time range :

```
select convert(varchar(6), DateCreated, 112) as Time, shopid, Count(ShopId) as Interest
    FROM Analytics
    WHERE DateCreated >= '2014' AND DateCreated < '2015'
    GROUP BY convert(varchar(6), DateCreated, 112), ShopId ORDER BY Interest DESC
```